# How to collect performance metrics in a Flask Application?

Tags: python, flask

What would be the best way to collect metrics on all HTTP requests made to a flask Application.

Things I would like to measure are :

- Latency - time for each request.
- Rate - No. of requests per minute etc.
- No of failures - If there is a failure, how many etc.

Also I want to group requests to a variable path as one. For e.g All requests to the route '/resource/' should be measured for the metric named "RESOURCE" and not individually for each resource.

I plan to do this currently by writing a decorator. The disadvantage being I need to add the decorator for each method.
Are there ways in which Flask can provide me hooks to measure these automatically.

Comment: That's nothing you should do on the application level but on the webserver level. And no, the builtin webserver is not something you should use in production.

Comment: I want to do this at the framework (flask/wsgi) level. I am not using the built in webserver.

Comment: @ThiefMaster collecting metrics in application and exporting them to Prometheus is a valid solution - WSGI server or proxies don't have all the information that matter, you cannot segment users, gather business metrics, separate speed by views (only by URL parsing), etc. There's plenty of advantages to this approach.

Answer (score 7):

Check out the documentation for the [`flask.Flask.before_request`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.before_request) and [`flask.Flask.teardown_request`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.teardown_request) decorators.  You'll want something simple and *fast* to send your metrics to - check out [graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com/) and [scales](https://github.com/Greplin/scales) for an example suitable backend.

Once you have your log aggregating back end then it is a simple matter of registering two functions to execute before and after each request.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [New-Relic](https://newrelic.com/docs/python/new-relic-for-python).
It supports flask and will give you the measures you want (and more).